# Forced damped oscillator - why am I getting infinite amplitude at resonance(incorrectly)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the **amplitude** of steady state response of the following differential equation:

$$\ddot{x}+2p\dot x + {\omega_0}^2x=\cos(\omega t)$$

---

A particular solution is
$$x_p=\Re{\dfrac{e^{i\omega t}}{\omega_0^2 - \omega^2 + i2p\omega}} $$

The amplitude at steady state is then $$A=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(\omega_0^2 - \omega^2)^2 + (2p\omega)^2}}$$

The denominator has **minimum** value when $\omega^2  =\omega_0^2 - 2p^2 $:
$$A=\dfrac{1}{2p\sqrt{\omega_0^2-p^2}}$$

This **expression seems to suggest that the amplitude goes to infinity as $p$ approaches $\omega_0$.**

But amplitude has to be **finite**(from other examples of LRC tank circuit etc).
Pretty sure I'm wrong but not able to see where. Any help?

Comment: You can have unphysical solutions to differential equations. Maybe that's the case here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice something very important...

When $p=w_0$, then you have (per your previous equation)

$w^2=-w_0^2$, which is to me an impossibility.

In the more correct order, since you have the previous equation, you have constraints on the system that prevents this to happen.

Put into other words, you find a solution for the maximum of $A$ that has no sense existing with $p$ close to $w_0$...

Comment: Ah right, but if I let $p$ approach $\omega_0$ and not let it actually equal. Then the amplitude increases to arbitrary large value?

Comment: Oh you mean there is a constraint $2p^2 \lt \omega_0^2$ ?

Comment: @across You can have $p$ being what you want. But in some cases, the solution to find minimum value of denominator will not yield to $w^2=w_0^2-2p^2$.

Comment: wow so my error is in working the *minimum* value(setting first derivative to 0) of the denominator.. and not taking constraints into account.. thank you so much it makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

If $\omega^2 = \omega_0^2 - 2p^2$ and we let $p$ approach $\omega_0$, we're going to have issues with $\omega$ being a real number.